# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lustdio

Tags: shared-library

So, I'm compiling a program from source, and the compilation fails when it tries to link "libustdio.so":

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lustdio
```

I'm pretty sure that its part of the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library, which I have already installed the libicu48 and libicu-dev packages.  Is there a way to figure out for sure if "libustdio.so" is a part of libicu48 or libicu-dev packages?  If so, then why is the library missing, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Using `apt-file`, I could not find the ustdio library, just a `ustdio.h` header file. Perhaps the wrong library is being linked?

Comment: Where would the sources from libicu-dev be found?

Comment: What do you mean by "sources"? You can list all files provided by an installed package using `dpkg -L libicu-dev`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that ustdio library is not actually a part of ICU anymore.  My issue stemmed from the fact that I did the `./configure` command before I installed libicu48 and libicu-dev, which returned the wrong results for the `icu-config --ldflags-icuio` command.  So, all of my makefiles had "-lustdio" instead of what was correct "-licuio".